# Angular: HttpInterceptor declared in library module intercepting requests outside of library

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-httpclient, angular-http-interceptors, injection-tokens

I have an issue in Angular whereby an implemented instance of `HttpInterceptors` declared in an Angular library is intercepting requests for `HttpClient` calls made outside the library (i.e. the consuming application).

I am struggling to understand why this is happening.

The `HTTP_INTERCEPTOR` injection is configured on the module declaration for my library, not my application.

My setup is as follows:

I have the `ng-mfe` library module declared as follows:

```js
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ConfigToken } from './tokens';
import { AuthHttpClient } from './services/auth/auth-http.service';
import { Config } from './models/module.model';
import { NgSelectModule } from '@ng-select/ng-select';
import { TokenInterceptor } from './services/auth/token.interceptor';

const components = [/* components */];
const imports = [CommonModule, HttpClientModule, NgSelectModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...components],
  imports: [...imports],
  exports: [...components],
  providers: [],
})
export class NGMfeModule {
  static forRoot(config: Config): ModuleWithProviders<NGMfeModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: NGMfeModule,
      providers: [
        AuthHttpClient,
        TokenInterceptor,
        {
          provide: ConfigToken,
          useValue: config,
        },
        {
          provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
          useClass: TokenInterceptor,
          multi: true,
        },
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

This library handles HTTP requests for an API and appends the relevant auth headers required to communicate with said API.

I have implemented a `HttpInterceptor` (`TokenInterceptor`) and provided the `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` injection token.

```js
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { filter, map, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { selectAccessToken } '../../state/shared-config/shared-config.selectors';

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private store: Store) {}

  /**
   * Intercept all HTTP requests and add the required auth headers to them
   *
   * @param req The request to intercept
   * @param next Transform HttpRequests into a stream
   */
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.store.select(selectAccessToken).pipe(
      filter((data) => !!data),
      switchMap((data) => {
        req = req.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${data}`,
          },
        });

        return next.handle(req);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

And finally, my `AuthHttpClient`:

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpOptions } from '../../models/http.model';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AuthHttpClient {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  get(url: string, options?: HttpOptions): Observable<Object> {
    return this.http.get(url, options);
  }
}
```

This is the library configuration, and my Angular application's module outside of the library is
as follows:

```js
import { NGMfeModule } from 'ng-mfe';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NGMfeModule.forRoot(/* config */),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And finally, in my `AppComponent` class, I have injected two services, one being my `AuthHttpClient` and the other being Angular's `HttpClient`:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthHttpClient, getAccessToken } from 'ng-mfe';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private http1: AuthHttpClient,
    private http2: HttpClient
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http1.get('test-url-1').subscribe();
    this.http2.get('test-url-2').subscribe();
  }
}
```

I would expect the call made by `http1` to be intercepted since that is an instance of `AuthHttpClient` which is declared in `ng-mfe`, but `http2` is an instance of Angular's `HttpClient` - and the `HttpClientModule` is imported in `AppModule`.

Maybe my understanding of Angular's singletons are wrong - but why are requests from `http2` being intercepted? Is my setup wrong (and is there a way to correctly configure my modules so this does not happen)? Or is this correct, and standard behaviour?

I previously had `Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` in my `AuthHttpClient` and `TokenInterceptor` service without them declared in the `providers` array in `NGMfeModule` but removed these so they are declared locally. But it has not made any difference. Is this correct, or should they always be `providedIn: root`?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions to your problem:

1. You could provide your own `HttpClient` implementation and inject
   your HTTP Interceptor there, as it is shown here: https://indepth.dev/posts/1455/how-to-split-http-interceptors-between-multiple-backends
2. With Angular 12 there are now `HttpContextTokens`. With these you
   can conditionally apply your logic in your HTTP Interceptor based on
   the existence of a specific token in the request:
   https://netbasal.com/new-in-angular-v12-passing-context-to-http-interceptors-308a1ca2f3dd